# Does drying temperature affect mean bread volume?

Tags: self-study, anova

A researcher has done an experiment to investigate the effect of drying temperature of wheat grain on the baking quality of bread. Three temperature levels were used, and the response variable measured was the volume of the loaf of bread produced. The data are as follows:
[image]

Does drying temperature affect mean bread volume? Use α=0.01

how to solve this problem?

P.s: I'm sorry, I did not intend to make other people do this homework for me..so let me just be clear...I don't really understand the questions..btw I do know how to do hypothesis testing and p-value testing method...but just I  don't know how to start...so I hope someone could help me to explain on how to do this kind of questions...

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, could you please add the [self-study] tag and tell us what your own thoughts about the problem are so far, and where you're getting stuck? (Note that CV is not meant as a place where you can get others to do your homework for you, but we're happy to point you in the right direction.)

Comment: +1 for writing an edit that clearly articulates what you are looking for.  Have you considered formulating null and alternative hypotheses?  Often that exercise is a good way to get started.

Comment: @Rian, you could start by writing what you have tried so far.